# SQL query to count rows in a table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a table (MYTABLE) in ms access 2003 with the following columns: table name, columnname and count
I would like to read through the table and dynamically create an SQL statement for each table and column, run the SQL to get the count and update the 'count' column in the table.

Eg

My table has

```
Tablename columnname count
PATIENT.  AGE.          0
```

Generate SQL select Count(*) from PATIENT WHERE AGE IS NOT NULL

Update 'count' column in my table with the vaL of count

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DCount Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211471%28v=office.11%29.aspx) in an `UPDATE` query.

```sql
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET [count] =
    DCount('*', [Tablename], '[' & columnname & '] Is Not Null');
```

That `UPDATE` statement examines each row in `MYTABLE`, gives `DCount()` the values stored in the `Tablename` and `columnname` fields, and stores the number returned from `DCount` in a field named `count` in the same row.

Comment: I got an error with this.how do I iterate through MYTABLE and paras the value for table and columnar to DCount?

Comment: I revised the answer to explain how that `UPDATE` statement does iterate through the rows contained in `MYTABLE`.  What was the error message you received?

Answer (score 0):

```
Update tablename
set count=(select Count(*) from PATIENT WHERE AGE IS NOT NULL)
where table_name=PATIENT
```

Comment: I assume you meant to say Update My table?